# Static variable in Javascript that is set only once

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, setter, getter

I was tearing my hair out to get this done...particularly for an html5 detection script. I wanted a variable that is set only once and that can't be overwritten again. This is it:

```
var StaticConfiguration = {};
StaticConfiguration.Main = {
    _html5: null
}
StaticConfiguration.getVariable = function(name) {
    return StaticConfiguration.Main["_" + name];
}
StaticConfiguration.setVariable = function(name, value) {
    if(StaticConfiguration.Main["_" + name] == null) {
        StaticConfiguration.Main["_" + name] = value;
    }
}
```

First, I define a global object StaticConfiguration containing all of these variables - in my case, just "html5". I set it to null, since I want to set it inside the application. To do so, I call

```
StaticConfiguration.setVariable("html5", "true");
```

It's set then. If I try to set it again, it fails - of course, since _html5 is not null anymore. So I practically use the underscore to "hide" the static variable.

This is helping me a lot. I hope it's a good approach - please tell me if not :)

Comment: In what situation would that variable get overwritten? I suppose that the detection script runs only once anyway?

Comment: Well, without the checking you could easily do

StaticConfiguration.setVariable("html5", "bla");

StaticConfiguration.setVariable("html5", "boom");

StaticConfiguration.setVariable("html5", "bang");


...and the variable would always be set - thats what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it's `true`, not `"true"` *all* strings (apart from the empty string) evaluate to true, including the string `"false"`.

Second off, do you really need to protect data like this? There's not really any way to safely run a user's Javascript i your context anyway. There's always a way around protection like this. If offending code really cared, it could just replace the whole `StaticConfiguration` object anyway.

Matthew's code is a better approach to the problem, but it doesn't follow a singleton pattern, but is a class that needs to be instanciated. I'd do it more like this, if you wanted a single object with "static" variables.

```
StaticConfiguration = new (function()
{
  var data = {}
  this.setVariable = function(key, value)
  {
    if(typeof data[key] == 'undefined')
    {
      data[key] = value;
    }
    else
    {
      // Maybe a little error handling too...
      throw new Error("Can't set static variable that's already defined!");
    }
  };

  this.getVariable = function(key)
  {
    if (typeof data[key] == 'undefined')
    {
      // Maybe a little error handling too...
      throw new Error("Can't get static variable that isn't defined!");
    }
    else
    {
      return data[key];
    }
  };
})();
```

Personal sidenote: I **hate** the "curly brackets on their own lines" formatting with a passion!

Comment: -1.  Since you're not creating a new object, this is `window`.

Comment: This is really great. Thanks a lot. I also prefer to put things in Singletons (Namespaces), so this is a perfect solution for me.

Comment: I'm liking the look of this, and it is better (but similar) to what I was trying to implement earlier today. Tell me, as the variable is a new closure, does it update and store new variables correctly each time it is called? Do I call `StaticConfiguration.setVariable(key, value)` like that? (bit of a noob here)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Crockford's article on [Private Members in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html). You can do something like this:

```
var StaticConfiguration = (function() {
  var html5; /* this is private, i.e. not visible outside this anonymous function */

  return {
    getVariable: function(name) {
      ...
    },

    setVariable: function(name, value) {
      ...
    }
  };
)();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var StaticConfiguration = new (function()
{
  var data = {}
  this.setVariable = function(key, value)
  {
    if(typeof data[key] == 'undefined')
    {
      data[key] = value;
    }
  };

  this.getVariable = function(key)
  {
    return data[key];
  };
})();
```

Similar to the other answer, but still allows arbitrary keys.  This is truly private, unlike the underscore solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little curious as to why you think that you have to go to this extent to protect the data from being overwritten. If you're detecting the browser, shouldn't it only be done once? If someone's overwriting it with invalid data, then I would assume that it would be a problem in the client implementation and not the library code - does that make sense?

As a side note, I'm pretty big on the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle, **especially** when it comes to client side scripting.

Comment: As I wrote it was important for me that the variable is set once or never. It's true that the browser detection should happen only once. For other things (GET-variables) it might be different. It could also happen that another class (prob. from another developer) jumps in and tries to set the same variable again - you're right, this should not happen, but my intention was to make it kind of "safe".

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm a little late to the party but in situations like this i usually

```
var data;

if (data === undefined || //or some other value you expect it to start with{
data = "new static value"
};
```