# Is there an elegant way to set a class property only once?

Tags: typescript, typescript-class

In TypeScript, while in a class, is there an elegant way to set a value only once? In other words, is there an equivalent of setting a value as `readonly` after giving it a value?

For example:

```js
class FooExample {
    public fixedValue: string;

    public setFixedValue(value: string): void {
        if (!this.fixedValue) {
            // this value should be immutable
            this.fixedValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not looking for a getter, because the class property could be changed within the class itself.

Comment: Return a new object instead, IMO, one with `readonly` for the property

Comment: Are you talking about `const` values?

Comment: @Chin.Udara unfortunately not. Those answers assume that the value is known when the constructor is called.

Comment: How about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423787/static-variable-in-javascript-that-is-set-only-once

Comment: What is the intended result if you don't call the setter before accessing the property?

Comment: @ebakunin - do you need a runtime or a compile-time behaviour? A smart setter could be used in case of the former, methinks

Comment: Yeah, as @OlegValter asked: is this just a runtime question or do you also want the compiler to yell at you if it notices you setting the property multiple times?  For the latter case you could use an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKkEMW), although assertion methods have a long list of caveats. If that seems like something you're interested in, I'd be happy to write up an answer.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz - huh, that's very clever, didn't think of the assertion myself. Do draft up an answer if you have some time either way - that's an inventive technique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the suggested answers and doing my own research I believe I have found the most elegant solution. You first define the value as an `Object` and then `freeze()` the `Object` after populating the related property.

```js
class FooExample {
    public fixedValue = {
        value: '';
    };

    public setFixedValue(value: string): void {
        if (!Object.isFrozen(this.fixedValue)) {
            this.fixedValue.value = value;
            Object.freeze(this.fixedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "smart" setter to achieve this. The idea is to define a setter on the class, delete the setter from within itself and define a read-only property via the `Object.defineProperty` method called with the descriptor whose `writable` property is set to `false`.

The "changed within the class itself" part could be achieved via another property redefinition. Don't forget to make the property `configurable` in the first place.

Here is how the full thing could look like (I do not think there is a more elegant way to do this) - runtime version of the answer is not TypeScript specific:

```js
class ReadonlyFields {
  set fixed(value) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "fixed", {
      value,
      writable: false,
      configurable: true,
    });
  }

  doSomething() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "fixed", {
      value: 24, //exact logic for changing the value is up to you
      writable: false
    });
  }
}

const r = new ReadonlyFields();
r.fixed = 42;
console.log(r.fixed); //42;
r.fixed = 24;
console.log(r.fixed); //42;
r.doSomething();
console.log(r.fixed); //24;
```

If you also want to enforce this from the type system standpoint, just make the property `readonly`:

```ts
class ReadonlyFields {
  readonly fixed!: number;

  setFixed(value: number) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "fixed", {
      value,
      writable: false,
      configurable: true,
    });
  }

  doSomething() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "fixed", {
      value: 24, //exact logic for changing the value is up to you
      writable: false,
    });
  }
}

const r = new ReadonlyFields();
r.setFixed(42); //OK
//@ts-expect-error
r.fixed = 24;
r.doSomething(); //OK
```